# Is there a software that computes simple particle decay kinematics?

Tags: particle-physics, kinematics, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, software

I was trying to figure out some details about a specific decay channel for a generic particle accelerator experiment. For instance if I have a proton proton collider with fixed energy, I would like to figure out what is the average decay length of a B meson, what would be the energy of its decay products (for a chosen channel) and similar things.

I know there is a lot of MC software used in high energy physics but I was just wondering if someone had a recommendation for one which is free and is not hard to use and configure when doing such simple things.

Comment: It seems doubtful that there would be a dedicated program for such a thing -- you can calculate these in a couple lines with pencil and paper.

Comment: Sounds lke you want EvtGen: https://evtgen.hepforge.org/

Comment: You could try MadGraph: http://madgraph.phys.ucl.ac.be/